# (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value when using hikari to connect PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I am using Hikari to connect the PostgreSQL 13 database in Spring Boot project, now the logs shows this waring:

```
[12:23:49:633] [WARN] - com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.isConnectionAlive(PoolBase.java:158) - HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@a54a5357 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
[12:23:49:634] [WARN] - com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.isConnectionAlive(PoolBase.java:158) - HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@5d8a4eb4 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
[12:23:49:636] [WARN] - com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.isConnectionAlive(PoolBase.java:158) - HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@18564799 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
```

first step I tweak the PostgreSQL 13 database `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` parameter like this:

```
alter system set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout='30min';
show idle_in_transaction_session_timeout;
```

I make sure the PostgreSQL 13 database `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` parameter was turned to 30min. The next step I tweak my maxLifeTime of Hikari in `application.properties` like this:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=900000
```

the Hikari maxLifeTime already less than database connection idle connection time, but the warning message did not disappeared. Am I missing something? what should I do to fix the warning message?

Comment: This PostgreSQL parameter has nothing to do with the problem. It is probably a network component that closes the connections.